# Ionic1 with angularjs file operation after scroll not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, file, ionic-framework, scroll

I use ionic v1 and angularjs. I did, file based hand terminal app. But after file operation, scroll not working.

Trick: When I click/focus some search box (get request) is working.

Cordova version: 6.2.0

Ionic version: 1.3.1

Scroll page html codes: Project start this scroll working 
[image: Scroll page]

But I do file operation like this(befor I read barkod and after open-write file operation. 
[image]

Comment: Please provide more details such as code snippets, images, and/or more explanation.

Comment: I added sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another config.xml entry which I've had some success with is:

```
<preference name="android-windowSoftInputMode" value="stateVisible|adjustResize" />
```

SOLITION : https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/689#issuecomment-36346056
it's worked for me.